# Bare metal automated backup for 14.04

Tags: backup

Wondering if anyone has a solution for an automated bare metal backup for server 14.04 running a lightweight gui?

I am using crashplan at the moment, however as I am 4 hours away from the site, I would love to have a solution where I could instruct over the phone to replace failed drive and boot from boot cd and recover entire system as in acronis which for some reason is $1000 for linux server.

My thoughts were going down the path of dd with a script to run at certain intervals, say once a day, clonezilla with the same method or the possibility of using acronis windows version under crossover, but unsure if that would work and worried about any overheads it might rack up.

Any thoughts appreciated.